# InputFile and Rerendering Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, apexinputfile

I am a new developer staffed on a Salesforce project. I am currently developing a custom app just to become familiar with APEX.

Right now, I have an "Upload" file button that reads a file provided by an InputFile tag in VF. However, I have a table with the current Contact object's user email address and another field that I am populating from the file.

I am running into an issue with rerendering and InputFiles. I have researched all of the answers on this forum and (to my knowledge) none of them seem to eliminate the error, which is the following:

*"apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute."*

I have attempted wrapping my button and InputFile in different ActionRegions, Forms, iframes, with no luck.

I would appreciate if anyone has run into this issue without success from the above methods and if anyone has come across a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with with js. it will show and hide on click of button. This might help you to display attachment based on your condition.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="inputFileExtension">
<apex:form >     
    <apex:commandButton onclick="toggle('mytag');return false;" value="Attachment"/>
    <div id="mytag" style="display:none">   
        <apex:inputfile value="{!blobString}"></apex:inputfile>
    </div>                            
</apex:form>
<script>
    function toggle(id) {
        var element =
        document.getElementById(id);
        if(element.style.display == 'none') {
        element.style.display = 'block';                
        }
        else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt Shravan. I modified your concept logic to my needs but apparently Salesforce does not update an record's field while refreshing a VF page unless I go back to the object itself first.

My objective was to import a file, and then populate a record field with that data and display the result on the same VF page.

Your answer will be useful in my future development however, thank you!